# Can't show some websites in iframe tag

Tags: html, http, iframe

I am trying to develop a page in which I can show more than 3 website at a time,
as below:

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/" /><p> iframe is not supported</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com/"></iframe>
   </li>
   <li>
      <iframe src="http://www.google.co.in"></iframe>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that it shows yahoo.com and google.co.in, but does not display Facebook in the iframe.

Comment: FWIW, you should close your first IFRAME tag and not make it self-closing.

Comment: EricLaw-MSFT- It doesn't work by closing the iframe tag , its something like facebook does not want to include itself in any other website's iframe tag.

Answer (score 42):

You have to check for HTTP response header X-Frame-Option of those sites. if its value is "DENY or SAMEORIGIN", then you can not load those website in the iframes.

DENY = No one can load the website in iframe. Even the same domain page wont be able to load.
SAMEORIGIN = only a page which is in same domain can load this website in iframe.

Comment: It is 'X-Frame-Options' NOT 'X-Frame-Option'.

Answer (score 10):

Since some websites have decided to disable embedding them in iframes theres nothing you can do with pure html solutions. You could create a serverside script (in PHP) that pulls the target site via your webserver and then use the html etc.

The only way I can think of that would enable you to check wether the site has loaded is to search the iframe for a specific element that exists on the target website (for example a div with a specific id or class on the Facebook's front page). The reason would be that different websites can handle being embedded into iframes differently and while some might display some content, some may display nothing etc and the only way to be sure is to check for real elements.

Comment: Zanfa : thanks for the reply. i guess there is no specific way to determine which sites allow themselves to be embedded in iframe unless i manually check some real element like for example i wanted the input to be from the user i.e. the website name but its not possible . Is there a work around ??

Comment: @Nikhil Sharma Unfortunately there's no way I can think of that would be 100% accurate (since you really don't know what a "full page" looks like because it might be ANY page). Then again, in most use-cases having an onload function on the iframes body element that checks whether there is any content at all or not should suffice. 

In conclusion, I think that this solution will work for most cases, and you shouldn't worry about this becoming a serious problem. I'd suggest implementing this as a preliminary solution and if problems do arise, look into it again and maybe find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

**facebook  does not want you to load their main site in frames**

```
<iframe src="http://m.facebook.com/" width="200" height="300" scrolling="auto" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

`width="200" height="300"` can be adjusted accordingly.*

What this does is load the mobile version of facebook in the frame instead of the main site.

[Reference](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=4949752878&topic=7081)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but is there any way around it and can i determine which sites will block this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object tag:
`<object data =  "https://facebook.com"></object>`

Comment: `<object>` is checked for the `X-Frame-Options` value too, thus it doesn't work as in the `<iframe>` case

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to do that, you can only iframe like button... someother not whole site.

Comment: The same behaviour is happening for other various sites as well , can i determine dynamically that the particular site will not allow this to happen .. eg : the same thing is happening for http://www.live.com http://www.youtube.com http://www.twitter.com http://www.blogspot.com