# iframe showing up blank

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to use a simple iframe on my website. But it is not showing up. Please see the screenshot. This is my code:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks[image: iframe showing blank]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373592/iframe-contents-cant-appear-in-firefox

Comment: @Lee The answer there doesn't apply here, w3schools.com is being accessed through https.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't show some websites in iframe tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663244/cant-show-some-websites-in-iframe-tag)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is right, it's w3schools.com that's the problem. Opening up the developer console reveals this:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

This means that w3schools.com will only work in a frame when the "origin" (the website your frame is on) is from w3schools.com. Otherwise, you'll just get a blank frame.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it seems that I can't load any external website in the iframe. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Yeah, a lot of websites do this it seems. Try a youtube embed: `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ"></iframe>`

Answer (score 3):

Pages from W3Schools are not displayed in `iframe` elements from different server because the W3Schools site implements an iframe blocking policy. In order to do this, it uses the **`X-Frame-Options`**. (See also [how to block website from loading in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843085/6002174).)

You can check whether a site implements this policy by inspecting its HTTP headers. For example, in Firefox, press `F12` to open the inspection tools, then go to **Network**, select one of the objects that were sent over HTTP and look at the headers (or filter the headers for e.g. "x-frame"). Below is what this looks like for W3Schools:

[image: Screenshot showing the HTTP Response header 'x-frame-option: SAMEORIGIN' in the Firefox Developer Toolbar]

Notice **x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN** in the lower right part of the screenshot. With `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` (or on some other sites `x-frame-options: DENY`) set on the server side, you will not be able to load pages from that site inside an `iframe` or a `frame`.

For more background, see [X-Frame-Options – How to Combat Clickjacking](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/), which also explains other values that can be used in the `x-frame-options` header.

If you want to test with a webpage from a server that does not block loading in iframes, try for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/.