# Changing Iframes HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I need a script to change the iframes src every certain amount of seconds. The time between the change is different between each one.

Example:
Page Loads
Google.com is loaded.
15 seconds later
Yahoo.com is loaded.
37 seconds later
Ask.com is loaded.
12 seconds later
Dogpile.com is loaded.
and so on and so forth.

I've tried that:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Monitor Presidência</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;">
        <div class="ui teal progress" data-percent="0" id="example1" style="width: 90%;margin-bottom: 0px">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui icon buttons" style="width: 10%">
            <button class="ui button" style="width: 25%" onclick="menos_um()">
                <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="ui button " style="width: 25%" onclick="inicia()">
                <i class="play icon"></i>
            </button>

            <button class="ui button" style="width: 25%" onclick="para_aplicacao()">
                <i class="pause icon"></i>
            </button>

            <button class="ui button" style="width: 25%" onclick="mais_um()">
                <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <iframe id="envase" class="frame_mon" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="www.google.com.br"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frete_hl" class="frame_mon" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;display: none;" src="www.yahoo.com.br"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frete_hl_acum" class="frame_mon" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;display: none;" src="www.terra.com.br"></iframe>



</body>
<script>
    var arr_monitores = ["envase", "frete_hl", "frete_hl_acum"];
    var num_monitor = 0;
    var progresso = 0;
    var myVar;

    var setintervalatualizaframe;


    function mais_um() {

        /*  if (num_monitor === 2) {
              num_monitor = 0;
          } else {
              num_monitor++;
          }

          $('.frame_mon').css('display', 'none');
          document.getElementById(arr_monitores[num_monitor]).style.display = "";*/

        progresso = 100;
        myStopFunction();
        inicia();
        /*  if (num_monitor === 2) {
              num_monitor = 0;
          } else {
              num_monitor++;
          }*/

    };

    function menos_um() {
        //progresso = 100;

        if (num_monitor === 0) {
            num_monitor = 2;
        } else {
            num_monitor--;
        }

        $('.frame_mon').css('display', 'none');
        document.getElementById(arr_monitores[num_monitor]).style.display = "";
        progresso = 0;
        myStopFunction();
        inicia();


    };

    function inicia() {
        clearInterval(setintervalatualizaframe);

        myStopFunction();
        myVar = setInterval(function () {
            if (progresso === 100) {
                progresso = 0;

                if (num_monitor === 2) {
                    location.reload();
                    //num_monitor = 0;
                } else {
                    num_monitor++;
                }
                $('.frame_mon').css('display', 'none')
                document.getElementById(arr_monitores[num_monitor]).style.display = "";
            };



            progresso++;
            progresso++;
            $('#example1').data('percent', progresso);
            $('#example1').progress();
        }, 3800);
    }

    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        //atualiza_frame();
    }
    inicia();

    function para_aplicacao(){
        clearInterval(myVar);
        atualiza_frame();
    }

    function atualiza_frame() {
        clearInterval(setintervalatualizaframe);
        setintervalatualizaframe = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById(arr_monitores[num_monitor]).src=document.getElementById(arr_monitores[num_monitor]).src;
        },1);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please add your code into snippet?.

Comment: i've tried that code, but it change the Iframes in the same time:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The way you are using setInterval and setTimeout is not properly
  handled, as it creates a timer id to schedule execution.         [0](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-do-i-pause-execution-in-javascript)
- A much more efficient way is to use the Promises async library, which is displayed below.           [1](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-sleep-function)
- For websites that won't work, they are using a response header that won't allow their pages to be framed. You can work around this with some back-end program, where the server loads the web files then forwards them.     [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663244/cant-show-some-websites-in-iframe-tag)

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title> Hello </title>
      <style>
          iframe {
              display: block;
              width: 1000px;
              height: 500px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
            }

            iframe:focus {
              outline: none;
            }

            button {
              display: block;
              margin: auto auto;
            }

            label {
              display: block;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
            }

            input {
              display: block;
              margin: auto auto;
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='main'>
        <button id='wait' onclick='wait()'>Wait</button>
        <label>Seconds</label>
        <input type='number' id='seconds' placeholder='milliseconds'>
        <button id='switching' onclick='webSwitch()'>Switch sites</button>
        <iframe id='switchMe' src='https://codepen.io'></iframe>
      </div>
      <script>
        //Array of webpages
       var webList = ["https://www.bing.com", "https://www.walmart.com","https://www.codepen.io"];
       //For tracking position in array
       var count = 0;

       //Function to be ran by event
       function webSwitch() {
          console.log('I have been called');
         if (count >= webList.length) {
           count = 0;
         }
         //Setting new URL
         document.getElementById('switchMe').src = webList[count];
         //Make sure to use next URL
         count++;
       }

       function wait() {
          console.log('Click!');
          var numMS = document.getElementById('seconds').value;
          sleep(numMS).then(() => {
              webSwitch();
          })
       }

       function sleep (time) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
       }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer, but is there a way thar it switches automatically with independent times per Iframe?

Comment: If you want them to have independent variables of time, one I can think of on the spot is having an array client-side that stores each time and an array of iframes by id. Match the two together via an update function that constantly refreshes itself on the page looking for changes. Have that call to a function to sync the iframes and time. Essentially you need to store the id and time seperate. Then call your sync function which can call your switch function too. Since JS classes have no class vars this is the only way I can think of unless maybe you find a way to use class methods instead.

Comment: can you give me a little example, please?

Comment: I would recommend reading into the prototype system. That has helped with the above code and has grown to allow similar thing to class vars. If an object is made with prototypes then possibly individuals times and website sets could be given to iframes with a specific id.