# Why can't I embed a specific URL in an iframe?

Tags: html

I have been trying to figure out why I can't embed this specific website with the code:

```
<iframe src="https://time.my-masjid.com/timingscreen/7695401e-d724-4adb-a188-ed33c2ce886e"></iframe>
```

When I do this, the iframe renders as a white box.

Comment: This question is duplicate. [See the similar one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663244/cant-show-some-websites-in-iframe-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default iframe show in smaller size but if you set the height width it will show your content You can try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://time.my-masjid.com/timingscreen/7695401e-d724-4adb-a188-ed33c2ce886e"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```