# Iframe can not access url

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the folding script on my aspx page

```
Function openurl() {
$("#page").append('<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe >')} openurl() ;
```

When the page loads it doesn't load the site, it says "website can not be reached" in my iframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you face any other console error message? because
1. You have used doubled delimeter (") within append function, use backslash escape. 
2. double quotes was not closed properly within append function.

Try this inside the openurl function:$("#page").append("<iframe id=\"test\" src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/\"/>")

Comment: @Saravanakumar sorry that was a typo,i have updated it to how i have it in my code

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663244/cant-show-some-websites-in-iframe-tag

check the X-Frame-Options too